# Line numbers in exception stack on winRT

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, symbols

We have a project for windows store app using WinRT (and XAML, C#). The problem is, that when some exception is thrown and I log the exception using `Debug.WriteLine(ex);`, there are no line numbers, so I do not know, where actually was the exception thrown. I have of course DEBUG configuration with "full" symbols set in Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Debug Info.

At first I thougth that it must be something in our project. HOwever, when I downlaoded some samples from microsoft and put there the following code, the exception still does not have line numbers.

```
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Test");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

If I put the code above for example into `OnNavigatedTo` method, I get:

```
System.Exception: Test
   at SDKTemplate.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

No line number there ...

In articles , books etc. there is no mention of the fact, that there should be no line numbers, but maybe I am missing something? Can it be related to version of VS? I am using VS2013. Or some system wide settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that Visual Studio isn't including the .pdb file (symbols) in the path where it executes the app.  On my machine, the path to the executable looks like this:

C:\Users\msmall\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DebugLineNUmbers\DebugLineNUmbers\bin\Debug\AppX

That's where VS packages up the executable and deploys it to the local machine to be run.  There's no .pdb file inside the AppX folder.  You end up with this:

```
System.Exception: Test
  at DebugLineNUmbers.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

However, you can move the .pdb from the Debug folder - just one level up - into the AppX folder and end up with the line numbers:

```
System.Exception: Test
  at DebugLineNUmbers.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) in
  c:\Users\msmall\Documents\Visual Studio 2013
  \Projects\DebugLineNUmbers\DebugLineNUmbers\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 36
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this really solved the problem. It's weird, because I am confident I have tried this and it did not work few weeks back :) That's why I posted this question. HOwever, now it works. Now, can you tell me pls why the VS is not copying pdbs automatically? Is there some settings in VS? How do you solve this in your projects.? I believe you dont copy it manually ... I also believe, that this is not the default behavior (pdbs not to be copied automatically)

Comment: Visual Studio by default does not include the symbols in the output folder for a Store app, because they are debug feature and give information about reverse-engineering a Store app.  

To enable this scenario, use a post-build event command to copy the pdbs to the output folder.

Keep in mind that VS knows how to read the symbols when you're actually debugging, and sets the debugger to the line when you encounter an exception.  However, you're not doing that - you're expecting that the app itself knows the line number for logging purposes.  This is at odds with the concepts of Store apps.

Comment: Hmm, it's really weird to me. I dont understand why this is not part of regular Debug configuration. Anyway, thanks for your input. I will accept the answer before the bounty will be due.

Comment: @MattSmall I have taken the .pdf files from debug into the Appx folder and then rebuild solution. But still the line numbers are not included.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post can help: [Line numbers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-get-exception-stacktrace-line-numbers-on-windows-phone.aspx)

Comment: I read the article. However, it deals with different problem. The guy needs line numbers form production (from release apps). My problem is, that i do not have line numbers even in debug ... which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet so here's a new answer which adds on to the accepted one.

Navigate to:

Project->[Project Name] Properties...->Build Events->Post-build event command line:

Add the following line to copy the pdb file to the AppX directory:

```
xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" "$(TargetDir)\AppX"
```